# AWS Lambda and Pusher intergration. How to send notification?

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification, aws-lambda, pusher

I am trying to use AWS Lambda to trigger Pusher notification to the browser. The same code works fine when run locally but fails to connect to Pusher servers when run on Lambda :

```
exports.handler = function (event, context) {

var pusher = new Pusher({
    appId: '<id>',
    key: '<key>',
    secret: '<secret>',
    cluster : "eu"
});

console.log(pusher);

pusher.trigger('test_channel', 'my_event', {"message": "hello world"});

context.succeed('hello world');
};
```

Any ideas why it does not work? Or how to make it working?

Comment: did you checked aws lambda security group settings whether it allows outbound traffic on port 80/443 or may be some other port where your pusher server listens?

Comment: Hi, did you get it work. Im having the same problem, dont get any error but no messages are broadcast. Hope you find a way to use Pusher with lambda.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add
`var Pusher = require('pusher');`